# storm supervisor exits when processing event

Tags: java, apache-storm

when i start the supervisor by issuing bin/storm supervisor it exits. The logs are with

```
2015-06-12T02:28:27.811-0700 b.s.event [ERROR] Error when processing event
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveDirectory(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/io/File;)V
at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__7480.invoke(supervisor.clj:489) ~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:241) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__7400.invoke(supervisor.clj:374) ~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__2625.invoke(event.clj:40) ~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
2015-06-12T02:28:27.834-0700 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error when processing an event")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error when processing an event")
at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:325) [storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__2625.invoke(event.clj:48) [storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

my storm.yaml has a basic configuration of

```
storm.zookeeper.servers: 
- "127.0.0.1"
storm.local.dir: "/mnt/storm"
nimbus.host: "127.0.0.1"
supervisor.slots.ports: 
- 6700
```

It starts fine until the spout receives a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like classpath of Storm doesn't include Apache commons-io v2.4 or wrong version.

Please check

> bin/storm classpath

to confirm classpath contains commons-io, and its version is 2.4. If it contains different version, you need to check manually (by javadoc) that it contains

> public static void moveDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir) throws IOException

You can refer https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v0.9.5/bin/storm#L101-L105 to how classpath is made.

Comment: commons-io is a jar that is shipped by default with storm package. I never messed up with those jars either. what can possibly go wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's why I'm suspecting that Storm classpath may be messed up. Can you paste your classpath?

Comment: what you said was right. I had 1.2 version in lib. I copied 2.4 version and it is working fine now. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils** class is missed. You should create a jar containing your code and all the dependencies of your code (except for Storm - the Storm jars will be added to the classpath on the worker nodes). Please, see more details how to run topology in the remote mode (in cluster) by link: https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster.html

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have not used file utils anywhere internally in my code. there are no dependencies over it also.